# Why isn't System.Data.SqlClient published by dotnet publish?

Tags: .net-core

I have a something.csproj project like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and a something.cs program like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SomethingNS
{
    public class Something
    {
       public static void Main()
       {
           var a = new SqlCommand();
       }
    }
}
```

Using dotnet 2.0, I execute:

```
dotnet publish
```

But I don't see the `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` at folder `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish\System.Data.SqlClient.dll`?

Why is that?

Comment: If I use `Version="4.4.0"` instead of `Version="4.1.0"`, it does show up there

Comment: WAG, but check your GAC to see if you have 4.1.0 installed.

Comment: I don't see any version of that dll in `C:\Windows\assembly`. (That's where I look in the GAC right?) But I do see different versions in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient`

Comment: Welp, if you searched the entire GAC and didn't find it installed, then my AG was a bit too W. Good luck.

Comment: @Will .NET Core applications do not use the GAC.

Comment: Bah, you kids with your net core and the hippety hoppety

Comment: dotnet v2 finally acquired the new `--self-contained` option, necessary if you also want the whole ball of wax that includes the entire runtime.  It is getting closer to actually being usable.

Comment: side note: '\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\...' means .Net Core 2 not being used. by default it should be '\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the .NET Core implementation of `System.Data.SqlClient` is different on windows and unix and thus makes use of .NET Core's ability to load the specific library needed.

You published a "portable" application, that is able to run on windows, linux, macOS etc. and the appropriate libraries will be loaded from e.g. the `runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Data.SqlClient.dll` or `runtimes/win/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Data.SqlClient.dll`. There are a few other platform-specific assets as well (a managed `System.IO.Pipes.dll` for unix and two native `sni.dll` files for 32 and 64 bit windows).

This is the reason there is no `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` in the root level of your publish output. There should be variants inside the `bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish\runtimes` subfolder.

Comment: Thanks Marin, I understand now

Comment: Well explained Martin, thanks! I was struggling with this today. I was confused why my deployment package was so big, and it turned out to be because of the runtimes folder. I tried setting the --runtime win-x64 param when doing dotnet publish, expecting it to then not include the libs for the other runtimes, but it ended up creating a publish directory over 90MB! After research, it looks like supplying the runtime turns it into a SCD - hence the size of the published app. Is there any way to specify the runtime such that it's not a SCD, and that it doesn't include all of the runtimes?

Comment: @Tophat, to publish a dotnet core that is not SCD and does not include all the runtimes please see the parameters that I used in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959856/net-core-3-0-nuget-dlls/57011227#57011227